# プラットフォームがサポートされていないエラー、TravisCIがうまくいきません

Tags: docker, travis-ci

#### 環境

ruby 2.6.5
rails 6
MySQL
M1チップ搭載macOS

#### 解決したいこと

プラットフォームがサポートされていないエラー、travis.ymlがうまく走りません。
また、sudoは非推奨、効果がないとエラーが出てます。代替はroot権限の記述が必要でしょうか？よくわかりません
わかる方がいらしたら教えてください！
よろしくお願いします。

#### 発生している問題・エラー

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 該当するソースコード

**.Travis.yml**

```yaml
language: ruby
os: linux
dist: xenial
sudo: true
services: docker

before_install:
  - docker-compose up --build -d

script:
  - docker-compose exec --env 'RAILS_ENV=test' web rails db:create
  - docker-compose exec --env 'RAILS_ENV=test' web rails db:migrate
  - docker-compose exec --env 'RAILS_ENV=test' web rails db:seed
  - docker-compose exec --env 'RAILS_ENV=test' web rails test
```

**Dockerfile**

```docker
FROM ruby:2.6.5

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl apt-transport-https wget && \
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - && \
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list && \
apt-get update && apt-get install -y yarn

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs yarn
RUN mkdir /fridge_app
WORKDIR /fridge_app
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock /fridge_app/
ENV BUNDLER_VERSION 2.1.4
RUN gem update --system \
    && gem install bundler -v $BUNDLER_VERSION \
    && bundle install -j 4
COPY . /fridge_app

RUN yarn install --check-files
RUN bundle exec rails webpacker:install

ENV PATH $PATH:/usr/local/src/bin

COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.6
    platform: linux/amd64
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: root
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/mysql

  web:
    build: .
    environment:
      region: ap-northeast-1
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/fridge_app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Comment: エラーメッセージは `unsupported config option for services.db: 'platform'` となっていて、これは `platform` オプションは使えません、という意味なのではないでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。M1対応してない事はないですよね？今のところ自分にはよくわからないです。

Comment: いえ、その様な意味ではなく、`platoform` というオプションそのものが廃止されたのではないか、という事です。

Comment: なるほど、ありがとうございます。調べてみます

Answer (score 0):

`x86_64` ではなく `amd64` と記載してみてください。

https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql?tab=description&page=1&ordering=last_updated

```
platform: linux/amd64
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
色々試しましたが、今のところ結果は本文に記載したとおりです。